# Update a table column depending on a column from the foreign key table

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have a problem where I have a table A which has a foreign key to table B, both tables contain a `From` and a `createdAt` column, both of type `datetime`.

I want to update the `From` column in table A to be either the `A.From` or `B.CreatedAt` depending on which one is bigger.

How should I approach this kind of problem? Can this only be done using cursor?

Comment: Please show the query you are having a problem with. Have you tried a `CASE` statement?

Comment: A cursor is rarely the answer.  There are times it's appropriate, for it's for a very good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to update the From column in table A to be either the A.From or B.CreatedAt depending on which one is bigger.

There's no need to update the `From` column in table A if `A.From` is equal to or larger than the corresponding `CreatedAt` value in table B.

Assuming your tables look something like:

```
DECLARE @TableA table
(
    ID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [From] datetime NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt datetime NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @TableB table
(
    ID integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    A_ID integer NOT NULL, -- foreign key
    [From] datetime NOT NULL,
    CreatedAt datetime NOT NULL
);
```

The update you need is of the form:

```
UPDATE TA
SET TA.[From] = TB.CreatedAt
FROM @TableA AS TA
JOIN @TableB AS TB
    ON TB.A_ID = TA.ID
WHERE
    TB.CreatedAt > TA.[From];
```